# How do I typedef a function pointer with the C++11 using syntax?

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef

I'd like to write this

```
typedef void (*FunctionPtr)();
```

using `using`. How would I do that?

Comment: very conf`using` indeed, especially because function pointer identifiers usually resided in the middle of a `typedef` statement and move to the front using `using`. At least that's where I'm lost.

Answer (score 261, accepted):

It has a similar syntax, except you remove the identifier from the pointer:

```
using FunctionPtr = void (*)();
```

Here is an [Example](http://ideone.com/dX3vQC)

If you want to "take away the uglyness", try what Xeo suggested:

```
#include <type_traits>

using FunctionPtr = std::add_pointer<void()>::type;
```

And here is another [demo](http://ideone.com/Fol5OL).

Comment: Dang, I hoped it would take away the ugliness `:(`

Comment: @rubenvb: `using FunctionPtr = AddPointer<void()>;` ;)

Comment: It's possible to use template type aliases to further clean up `add_pointer<void()>::type`: Using the suggestion here: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-proposals/xDQR3y5uTZ0/VKmOiLRzHqkJ you can write `pointer<function<void>>`.

Comment: These type aliases change the type syntax from obscure, inside-out syntax to a simple left-to-right syntax, which largely eliminates the need for custom typedefs for specific APIs that make it easier to write that API's compound types.

Comment: In C++14, you will be able to write:
 using FunctionPtr = std::add_pointer_t<void()>;

Comment: Yes, because type aliases will be used. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3655.pdf

Comment: The latter is far uglier than the former.

Comment: @Apollys In hindsight I have to agree with you.

Comment: Shouldn't it be with `typename` like `using FunctionPtr = typename std::add_pointer<void()>::type;`

Comment: @Oguzhan You only use `typename` when you're using a template parameter. So if you had `template<class T>` somewhere and wanted to use `T` in this context, you would use `typename`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thanks for reminding, yes on my case it was a template  `template<typename returnType, typename ...Params>using FuncType = typename std::add_pointer<returnType(Params...)>::type;`

Comment: using foo = void(int);

Comment: Is there a difference between `std::add_pointer<void()>::type` and `std::function<void()>`? When would I use which one?

Comment: `add_pointer<void()>::type` comes out to `void(*)()`. It's a pointer. `function<void()>` is a class. The difference is that `std::function` is used when you need type erasure. You can assign a lambda function to `std::function`, and any class that has a `void operator()()` method. With `void(*)()` you can only assign raw function to it. Use `void(*)()` by default because `std::function` isn't usually needed.

Answer (score 67):

The "ugliness" can also be taken away if you avoid typedef-ing a pointer:

```
void f() {}
using Function_t = void();    
Function_t* ptr = f;
ptr();
```

http://ideone.com/e1XuYc

Comment: This is an interesting approach, though I might be worried I'd forget the `*` later and get confusing errors.

Comment: This definitely is the nicest version presented here. Thank you.
And I prefer seeing a pointer, as it is a function pointer after all.

Answer (score 16):

You want a `type-id`, which is essentially exactly the same as a declaration except you delete the `declarator-id`.  The `declarator-id` is usually an identifier, and the name you are declaring in the equivilant declaration.

For example:

```
int x
```

The `declarator-id` is `x` so just remove it:

```
int
```

Likewise:

```
int x[10]
```

Remove the `x`:

```
int[10]
```

For your example:

```
void (*FunctionPtr)()
```

Here the `declarator-id` is `FunctionPtr`. so just remove it to get the `type-id`:

```
void (*)()
```

This works because given a `type-id` you can always determine uniquely where the identifier would go to create a declaration.  From 8.1.1 in the standard:

> It is possible to identify uniquely the location in the [type-id] where the identifier would appear
>   if the construction were a [declaration]. The named type is then the same as the type of the
>   hypothetical identifier.

Answer (score 10):

How about this syntax for clarity? (Note double parenthesis)

```
void func();
using FunctionPtr = decltype((func));
```

Comment: What do the double parenthesis mean in this context? A *reference* to a function pointer?

Comment: Your `FunctionPtr` is not a function pointer, but `decltype(&f)` is, see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=77def487d5ed99885c0523d48c2ae7a1-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba).

Comment: @1234597890 FunctionPtr is a non-const lvalue reference to type 'void ()'

Comment: @rubenvb:
You are right. It is not a function pointer but a lvalue reference to the function (type). Which is why static_assert fails...<br/>
Try using FunctionPtr: 

    using namespace std;
    #include <iostream>
    
    void do_f()
    {
        cerr << "what?\n";
    }
    
    
    void f();
    using FunctionPtr = decltype((f));
    using FunctionPtr2 = decltype(&f);
    // Doesn't work
    //using FunctionPtr3 = decltype(f);
    
    
    int main()
    {
    FunctionPtr ff = do_f;
    
    ff();
    
    FunctionPtr2 ff2 = do_f;
    ff2();
    }

Answer (score 8):

Another approach might using auto return type with trailing return type.

```
using FunctionPtr = auto (*)(int*) -> void;
```

This has the arguable advantage of being able to tell something is a function ptr when the alias begins with "auto(*)" and it's not obfuscated by the identifier names.

Compare

```
typedef someStructureWithAWeirdName& (FunctionPtr*)(type1*, type2**, type3<type4&>);
```

with

```
using FunctionPtr = auto (*)(type1*, type2**, type3<type4&>) -> someStructureWithAWeirdName&;
```

Disclaimer: I took this from Bean Deane's "Easing into Modern C++" talk