# Could someone explain the meaning of "using"?

Tags: c++, using

I do not understand below usage of using in C++.
What's difference with typedef?
Could someone explain it with some example?

```
template<typename DataType>
class DataWriter
{
using ObjType = std::function<void(DataType)>
// ...
}
```

Comment: It's a syntactic sugar brought by C++11. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498969/how-do-i-typedef-a-function-pointer-with-the-c11-using-syntax).

Comment: In this particular case, it's syntactic sugar.  It has other, awesome, uses in addition that typedef doesn't do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference *in your example* to a `typedef`.

Those are identical:

```
typedef int a;
using a = int;
```

In general, it is more versatile though, which is the reason it was introduced:

- It can be templated.

  ```
  template<class X> using smart = std::unique_ptr<X>;
  ```
- It can be used to import symbols into the current scope.

  ```
  struct Derived : Base {
      using Base::Fun;
  };
  ```

Comment: I don't think the asker wanted an enumeration of all scenarios were the keyword `using` appears. He was talking about alias declarations in particular.

Comment: @Columbo: Thanks for the edit. And I don't think the OPs focus is quite that narrow, even if that was the example he gave.

Comment: Thanks all. Firstly, I want to know this "using" usage, secondly I also  want to know the reason why C++ 11 introduce this language sugar, I guess there are some reasons.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. [dcl.typedef]/2:

> A *typedef-name* can also be introduced by an *alias-declaration*. The
>   identifier following the `using` keyword becomes a *typedef-name*
>   [..]. **It has the same semantics as if it were introduced by the
>   `typedef` specifier.**

I.e.

```
using ObjType = std::function<void(DataType)>;
```

Is equivalent to

```
typedef std::function<void(DataType)> ObjType;
```