# How do I typedef a method pointer with the C++11 using syntax?

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef, using

I'd like to write this

```
class A {
   ...
};
typedef void (A::*MethodPtr)();
```

using `using`. How would I do that?

Would appreciate answers both with and without using `type_traits`.

(The answer for regular functions can be found here: [How do I typedef a function pointer with the C++11 using syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498969/how-do-i-typedef-a-function-pointer-with-the-c11-using-syntax))

Comment: What advantages does `type_traits` have? I cannot imagine why you would want to use it.

Comment: See the related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498969/how-do-i-typedef-a-function-pointer-with-the-c11-using-syntax for how it helps there. I imagine it might help here as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
using MethodPtr = void (A::*)();
```

Quite similar to a function pointer, in fact.

Answer (score 3):

```
using MethodPtr = void (A::*)();
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in `<type_traits>` that's directly helpful here (you could go from a pointer to member function to a function, but not the reverse). But we could write our own member version of the `add_pointer`:

```
template <class C, class T>
using mem_ptr_t = T C::*;
```

So creating a pointer to `A` that is a function of type `void()` is just:

```
using MethodPtr = mem_ptr_t<A, void()>;
```

That's more verbose than the simple approach, but since you asked!

Comment: `mem_ptr_t` would be a more concise name.