# The rationale of C++ disallowing array of functions?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

What is the underlying rationale (technical or conceptual) that C++ does not allow defining array of function type? E.g.

```
using fn_t = int(int);
fn_t ary[2]; // ERROR (ref: ISO/IEC-14882 [dcl.array])
```

Comment: `int(int)` is a function type?

Comment: @user0042 Why not?

Comment: A function is code, not data. C++ allows, however, arrays of pointers to functions.

Comment: if you use that kind of `using` syntax, you have to use pointers of `fn_t`, as `fn_t` is not a function pointer. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23740727/5487099) post.

Comment: @axiac No code here though, anyway, so this means that a function is an abstraction of "behavior", and behavior does not imply storage meaning ?

Comment: Yes, it's a function type. What is the parameter to `std::function<>`, do you guys reckon?

Comment: You probably meant `int(*)(int)`.

Comment: I believe the memory representation of a function type is not defined by the standard; `sizeof` a function type is illegal. Naturally you can't have an array of things with no size.

Comment: @philsumuru - I don't know about abstractions, I just know the c++ standard names it an "incomplete type". And you can't create objects of an incomplete type. Kind of like `T[]` is incomplete, and you can't have a `T [10][];`

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks, but again why such type is "incomplete" is a bit confusing.

Comment: @philsumuru - Well, if you don't know the array size, how will you allocate storage for it? In the same fashion, simply knowing a functions return and parameter types doesn't tell you much about it.

Comment: I'd imagine the reason is mostly historical and probably for systems that have separate (as in physically seperate) memory for functions (i.e. code) and other objects (i.e. data), you wouldn't be able to create functions them in the same way. New language features like lambdas help bridge the gap.

Comment: @Niall Personally I still suspect that it is because of the "abstraction" reason; function is a kind of "behavior" and behavior itself does not imply storage. But anyway it has also technical reasons.

Comment: Since C++ does not have support for creating new functions at runtime there is no need to keep them by value anyhow.

Comment: As for the **true underlying reason** that this is forbidden, you’d have to ask one of the people who wrote the standard. I understand some of them actually answer emails if you send them a nice one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given two random functions I just made up:

```
int a( int x, int y )
{
  return x * y;
}

int b( int x, int y )
{
  int result = 0;
  for (int xi = 1; xi <= x; xi++)
  for (int yi = y; yi >  0; yi--)
    result += xi * xi;
  return result;
}
```

How do you suggest I put them in an array?

I could compile them, I suppose, then just have an array of max( sizeof(a’s bytecode), sizeof(b’s bytecode) ). But now I have some additional considerations:

- Where does this array go?
  Some processors can run code from anywhere in memory. Some cannot.
- What about security attributes for the code?
- What about relocation considerations?
- How do I call this function?
  Can I use the processor’s usual calling conventions?
  Or will this require extra behind-the-scenes magic?
- What happens when I want a pointer to the array?
  What happens if I move the array and then call the pointer?
- What about exceptions and other abnormal signal considerations?

This is just the tip of the iceberg. There are *a lot* of technical considerations to doing this kind of thing.

Which leads to the main consideration:

**What advantage would this give over pointers to functions?**

With a pointer to a function, I can do everything I otherwise wanted to do:

```
int (*fs)(int,int)[] = { a, b };

int x = fs[0]( 10, 10 );
int y = fs[1]( 10, 10 );
```

The language is designed with several goals — two of the most important being **simplicity** and **flexibility**.

Doing what you would reduces both simplicity and flexibility for everyone: compiler writers, compilers themselves, runtime management, speed, safety, etc.

EDIT:
**tl;dr** Because it offers no advantage over pointers or references to functions, but plenty of drawbacks.

Comment: I think it is the first time someone stated that **simplicity** was one of the most important C++ design goals.

Comment: Well, it was a design goal for **C**, LOL.

Comment: @VTT yes, i think it should have been 0-overhead abstraction and direct hardware mapping. Anyway this is a technical consideration to my question.

Comment: C certainly did simplify many aspects of software development back then, that is one of the reasons it got so wide speeded after all. However the simplicity of language itself seems to always been of the last concern. Just take a look at crazy spiral function pointers array declaration syntax.

Comment: I don't think that holds up as a good example. The syntax is simple and logical. It may be supposed that a simpler, less confusing syntax could have been devised, but that is a matter of over four decades’ hindsight.

Comment: @Dúthomhas Are you serious by calling syntax "simple and logical"? If it was like this than people wouldn't have to create [special service](https://cdecl.org/) to translate C declarations into human language.

Answer (score -2):

> What is the underlying rationale (technical or conceptual) that C++ does not allow defining array of function type?

What is a function? It's just some code at an address. Conceptually it's a singleton, since there is no reasonable way to copy one or allocate one on the heap. Why would you? It already exists. It has a name, and that name yields a function pointer - the address of the code.

There is a concept of a 'function object', which is more equivalent to the 'first class function' of high level languages like python or javascript.

But under the hood it's modelled as a structure containing the address of code (a function pointer) and some state.

There are a few ways to create an array of functions: (this code is c++14)

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int a(int i) {
    std::cout << "called a with " << i << std::endl;
    return i;
} 
int b(int i) {
    std::cout << "called b with " << i << std::endl;
    return i + 1;
} 
int c(int i) {
    std::cout << "called c with " << i << std::endl;
    return i + 2;
} 

int main()
{
    // make life easier by creating a typedef
    using raw_fptr = int (*)(int);

    // an array of function pointers
    raw_fptr raw_ptrs[] =
    {
        a, b, c
    };

    // a typedef of a std::function object
    using fobject = std::function<int(int)>;

    // an array of function objects
    fobject fobjects [] = {
        &a,                     // can capture a function pointer
        [](int i) -> int {      // or a lambda
            return b(i);
        },
        std::bind(&c, std::placeholders::_1) // or a binder
    };

    for (auto&& f : raw_ptrs)
        f(0);

    for (auto&& f : fobjects)
        f(1);

}
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I suspect the reason is that the OP wants to have an array of functions, not pointers or references to functions.

Comment: Thanks but I do know how to fix my situation; I just want to know the *underlying consideration* of such language rule.

Comment: @Dúthomhas a function pointer *is* to all intents and purposes a function, and the second form captures function objects. People can downvote all they want, but I think I answered the question :)

Comment: @RichardHodges I'm going to disagree there. A function pointer is not a function. OP knows the difference between the two and is not asking _how_ to do it, but _why_ the standard forbids one.

Comment: @philsumuru there is no such thing as a 'function' as you wrote it - what you wrote was a function signature. You can store a function pointer because that's all there is - the address of code. A function object (e.g. lambda) is a combination of a function pointer plus instance pointer.
As for the reasons for all this, it's historical. c++ has its roots in c. c has no concept of a 'first class function object' like javascript or python.

Comment: It is certainly possible (actually not that unusual) to emit some executable machine code at runtime and technically nothing prevents one from storing it in arrays. But that would be just arrays of (special) bytes anyway since language does not support expressing this differently.

Comment: @RichardHodges So again what is "function signature" then? C++ array also forbids elements as type `void`, references, and abstract class type. What makes function signature differentiates with them?

Comment: @Dúthomhas the reason that a function pointer can be assigned from a captureless lambda is because a captureless lambda is 'just' a function pointer. From the point of view of code, a function pointer and a function are equivalent. given `int (*p)(int)` you can call `(*p)(1)` or `p(1)` and the results are exactly the same.

Comment: @RichardHodges You’re arguing two halves in order to justify equating two different things. OP wasn’t asking what you are answering. And I’m not interested in arguing the details.